# Nginx reverse_proxy from domainA.it/appA to domainB.it/appB maintining the original url ( domainA/appA )

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

i need to implement this configuration in my nginx web server ( reverse_proxy ):

I have a domain like [www.domainA.it](http://www.domainA.it) where respond my site, then i need to publish antother "app" from my [www.domainA.it/appA](http://www.domainA.it/appA), the application respond to another domain like [www.domainB.it/appB](http://www.domainB.it/appB)

The nginx configuration that i have implement is like this:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name www.domainA.it domainA.it;
    error_log ssl_error.log;
    access_log ssl_access.log;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  my.key;
    include /etc/nginx/sec.conf;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://my-backend;
    }

    location /appA {
        proxy_pass https://domainB/appB/;
        proxy_http_version                 1.1;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
}
```

With this configuration i recive the error like this:

https://www.domainA.it/appB/... 404 not found

https://www.domainA.it/appB/... 404 not found

.
.
.

If i expose the same location www.domainA/appB , all it's work fine

How i can do this ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: I can only see `appA` in your nginx config? Please share the whole configuration or add the `/appB` location? Do you want a transparent path or do you want to send `/appA` and `appB` to your backend? With your configuration your backend will receive a request https://domainB/appB/appA/.... .

Comment: Hi, the config have only location / and location /appA . Yes is like transparent path , when i call www.domainA/appA , i want that the proxy_pass send me to www.domainB/appB but maintain the url www.domainA/appA. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is `www.domainB/appB` on the same server as `www.domainA/appA`?

Comment: No, is on another server

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this issue by modifing the backend context.
It works all fine with this configuration:

```
location /appA {
    proxy_pass https://domainB/appA/;
    proxy_http_version                 1.1;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

}